# Vertical alignment with furigana in title

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

While editing [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3856), I noticed that the ruby (or furigana) causes problems with vertical alignment when used in the title. It is okay that the ruby takes up some vertical space, but it should not affect vertical alignment. In the title of the question that I linked or of [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3629), the ruby is vertically lowering the entire character that is rubied. If possible, I think this should be fixed. In a strict view, this is a bug, but it may also be considered as a feature request. Sometimes, the vertical alignment appears correctly as in the title of [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3848)

This is reproduced with Firefox but not on Internet Explorer or Chrome according to the comments below.

Comment: Is this still an issue with current (non-beta) browsers? I'd like to close this bug if it can't be reproduced.

Comment: @Oded As far as I can tell this doesn't happen with any recent version of Firefox (or SeaMonkey).  Something similar *does* happen when I use Safari on iPhone and use the full interface rather than the mobile interface ([example screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Ssm.jpg)), but I'm not sure if that's something fixable.

Comment: @snailboat could you point out the problem more explicitly?  I'm sorry to be tedious, but I don't know enough about written Japanese to identify the problem.

Comment: @BenCollins With the new version of the furigana script, [it's now rendering properly on my phone](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w69WT.jpg).  (On the old screen shot, the problem is that 我 and 輩 were shrinking to make room for the わ and はい on top.  You can see how the が between them was much bigger.)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the server uses the ruby support in the browser if available (e.g. IE, Chrome) and uses the stylesheet-based emulation otherwise (e.g. Firefox).  In my environment (Windows), the issue reproduces with Firefox 8.0 but does not reproduce with Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 or Chrome 15.0.874.121 m.  Therefore, this might be caused by some glitch in the stylesheet-based emulation.

*Update in response to revision 3 of the report*: With Firefox 8.0 on Windows, the issue reproduces in all three questions you linked to, and not only in the titles of questions but also in text.

Comment: I see. I had that problem with Firefox 9.0 on linux. I checked it now with Chrome, which is the same version as yours but is on linux, and the problem is not reproduced. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I came to realize that the problem is complex. It sometimes happens, and sometimes not. I edited my question.

Comment: @sawa: Because Firefox 9.0 has not been released, you must be using a beta version.  As a general advice on bug reports, it is better to check with a released version of a browser before reporting a bug if you can.

Answer (score 0):

@Oded actually took care of this, but we've updated the furigana script on our end.